# GitKraken can't connect to SSH. Invalid Key

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, gitkraken

I've a repo at a server and gitKraken can connect, clone, push and pull over ssh with one pc without problems, i did't do any settings on this pc and he's connecting. Now i've installed gitKraken to another pc and can't connect cause invalid ssh key. I've tried to generate keys, load them on the server, load the server keys on my pc. Nothing's working.

Comment: You're going to need to add more information. At the moment there's not enough to give accurate help.

Comment: I've hosted an Ubuntu Server and initialized a Repo at /home/git/Repo. With the 1st pc when I try to clone git@myurl.com:/home/git/Repo, he asked for the password of the user git and clone. At the 2nd pc, he don't ask for password and write Invalid SSH key.

Comment: You have to tell GK where you keep your keys: `Preferences -> Authentication -> General` lets you set the paths for your private and public SSH key files.

Comment: at the 1st pc in the users documents folder. At this pc its not important which key i choose, he connects independently from the key. At the 2nd pc they are stored in Documents too, but there I can choose whatever I want, it isn't connecting.
Are keys necessary? I only want to connect with username and password like at the 1st pc and like PuTTy.

Comment: @kowsky
path: `C:\Users\username\keys\gitkraken_rsa` and `C:\Users\username\keys\gitkraken_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've generated now a key pair and put it into GitKraken. I know this is default knowledge but for people who have the same problem or don't know how to work with ssh keys this tutorial is good to understand: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/OpenSSH_Public_Key_Authentifizierung_unter_Ubuntu.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem last week.
Tried several methods found online but none of them actually works for me.

Finally solved by generating a new pair of gitkraken_rsa keys by gitkraken itself(under Gitkraken/Preference/Authentication) and pointed to them(without using the default rsa keys).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your remote is set correctly. Gitkraken will allow you to clone by pasting in the "git clone" command but it will erroneously set that as the remote origin instead of just the git@bitbucket.org:...